# Run an exe from CURRENTDIRECTORY before installation begins

Tags: wix

```
<Property Id="TestDestination" Value="CURRENTDIRECTORY" />
    <CustomAction Id="StopAll" Property="TestDestination" ExeCommand="[CURRENTDIRECTORY]\stopall.exe" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no">
    </CustomAction>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="StopAll" Before="RemoveFiles" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I want to start a job before installation begins. I tried different kind of ExecuteSequences. The exe didn't start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it that stopall.exe is going to do? Where is it located during the install and how do you get it there? Also, I don't know what CURRENTDIRECTORY is used for but at the end of one of my installs it was set to C:\Windows\SysWOW64. I think you might want to be using SOURCEDIR which is set to the location of the actual msi file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. CURRENTDIRECTORY is the right location, where the file is located! The exe stops some processes and has to run before installation begins. But the exe didn't run. What is wrong? Or is it another way to run jobs before installation begins?

Comment: What is stopall.exe and how does it get wherever it is on the target machine? If you want to run an executable before the installation starts you should probably be using a burn bootstrapper. I'm not sure that CURRENTDIRECTORY is a static value throughout the install it may change several times. You should really get a log (msiexec /i <Installer.msi> /l*v log.txt) to actually see what is happening during your custom action call.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I try it...